Problemas para seleccionar elementos de un combobox con Selenium
Lo que pasa es que cuando intento seleccionar un elemento de un desplegable, Selenium no encuentra dichos elementos, es como si no existieran en la pagina. Me di cuenta que cuando se despliega el combobox se crea el siguiente fragmento de codigo fuera del Body.
Pero lo que hay dentro de ese fragmento de código no me deja seleccionarlo con Selenium, Selenium no lo encuentra. tampoco veo que haya algún iframe al que pueda acceder.
Aclaro que este sitio esta hecho con Angular Material
codigo:
    <div class="cdk-overlay-backdrop cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing"></div>
    <div class="cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box" dir="ltr"
        style="top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <div id="cdk-overlay-0" class="cdk-overlay-pane"
            style="min-width: 539.75px; font-size: 14px; top: 402.625px; left: 144.25px; transform: translateX(-16px) translateY(-13px);">
            <div class="mat-select-panel-wrap ng-tns-c154-16 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transformPanelWrap ng-star-inserted">
                <div role="listbox" tabindex="-1"
                    class="ng-tns-c154-16 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transformPanel mat-select-panel mat-primary"
                    id="mat-select-2-panel" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-labelledby="mat-form-field-label-11"
                    style="transform-origin: 50% 20.875px 0px; font-size: 14px; opacity: 1; min-width: calc(100% + 32px); transform: scaleY(1);">
                    <mat-option _ngcontent-ctb-c701="" role="option"
                        class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator mat-active ng-tns-c154-16 ng-star-inserted"
                        id="mat-option-12" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" style=""><!----><span
                            class="mat-option-text">
                            Head Office
                        </span><!---->
                        <div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-option-ripple"></div>
                    </mat-option><!---->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> ```

